# I receive 404 Not Found Error on Postman when I run a flask app

Tags: python, flask

This is the first hands-on for me in Flask.
I am trying to create Web-API to deploy a python function. Before that, I want to test it using Postman. The Test fails to run and I received 404 Not Found Error message.

Flask version: 1.1.2

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/postmanpost", methods=['POST'])
def math_operation():
    if (request.method=='POST'):
        operation=request.json['operation']
        num1=int(request.json['num1'])
        num2 = int(request.json['num2'])

        if(operation=='add'):
            r=num1+num2
            result= 'the sum of '+str(num1)+' and '+str(num2) +' is '+str(r)
        if (operation == 'subtract'):
            r = num1 - num2
            result = 'the difference of ' + str(num1) + ' and ' + str(num2) + ' is ' + str(r)
        if (operation == 'multiply'):
            r = num1 * num2
            result = 'the product of ' + str(num1) + ' and ' + str(num2) + ' is ' + str(r)
        if (operation == 'divide'):
            r = num1 / num2
            result = 'the quotient when ' + str(num1) + ' is divided by ' + str(num2) + ' is ' + str(r)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Pycharm Terminal :

[image]

Postman Test Results:

[image: > Blockquote]

Comment: Works for me as expected. Did you make sure to POST against `http://localhost:5000/postmanpost` and _not_ against `http://localhost:5000/postmanpost/`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that. As shown above I POST against http://localhost:5000/postmanpost .

Answer (score 0):

I'm also Facing this problem.
And i searched on google there is no Answer after trying so many things i found one solution for this Question.
And the solution is just change the port and your issue will resolve.

#Answer ->

`if __name__ == '__main__': app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port='8080')`

After this My postman is identifying the API correctly.